# Tree Menu with grayed-out/disabled text with compact framework limitations

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I'm editing an old program written in C# in VS2005 written for a desktop/mobile application.

On the mobile application I'm limited to using .NET Compact Framework 3.1 and due to this I am finding it difficult to achieve something that would normally be quite simple.

I wish to have certain areas of a tree menu grayed-out/disabled. The reasoning behind this is that the client can have one of three different versions of the application; lite, full and pro.

If the client is using a lite version of the product, I wish to have the options that the lite version lacks grayed out, that way the client is able to see what they are missing. At the moment I am limited to simply making the unavailable options invisible to them.

So to put it simply, is there a way in which I would be able to achieve this within the constraints of .NET compact framework 3.1?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean Compact Framework 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can realize the derieved classes from TreeView and TreeNode and realize such behavior.

```
   using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SmartDeviceProject3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        private System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu mainMenu1;
        private TreeViewEx treeView1;

        public Form1()
        {
            this.mainMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu();
            this.treeView1 = new TreeViewEx();

            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.treeView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.treeView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.treeView1.Name = "treeView1";
            this.treeView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 268);
            this.treeView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
            this.AutoScroll = true;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 268);
            this.Controls.Add(this.treeView1);
            this.Menu = this.mainMenu1;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeViewNodeEx()
            {
                Text = "Enabled"
            });
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeViewNodeEx()
            {
                Text = "Disabled",
                Enabled = false,
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }

    public class TreeViewEx 
        : TreeView
    {
        protected override void OnAfterSelect(TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            var node = e.Node as TreeViewNodeEx;
            if (node != null && !node.Enabled)
            {
                return;
            }
            base.OnAfterSelect(e);
        }
    }

    public class TreeViewNodeEx 
        : TreeNode
    {
        private bool _enabled = true;
        public bool Enabled
        {
            get
            {
                return _enabled;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_enabled != value)
                {
                    _enabled = value;
                    if (_enabled)
                    {
                        this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Neat little trick. I was about to tell him it could not be done on Windows Mobile, and to make it work he'd have to find a way to create his own controls - which is exactly what you did! Now, all he needs to do is find a way to market his tool for people who have long moved away from Windows Mobile devices.